# Linux Kernel Atomic Operations with Memory Barriers

Tags: linux-kernel, atomic, memory-barriers

I am trying to better understand memory barriers in the Linux Kernel. I am wondering if my implementation below would result in valid atomic operations if these threads ran in parallel. I am not focusing on a specific architecture in this implementation...I would want this to work for any architecture. Basically my implementation has a smp_mb() after any write operation and barrier() before any read operation. And if this implementation would not work, would it work for a single writer thread with one or many reader threads?

```
int a = 0;
int *b = &a;
int c;

#define my_atomic_set(var, val) { \
    *var = val;                   \
    smp_mb();                     \
}

#define my_atomic_set_ret(var, val) { \
    barrier();                        \
    int ret = *var;                   \
    *var = val;                       \
    smp_mb();                         \
    ret;
}

#define my_atomic_add(var, val) { \
    barrier();                    \
    int tmp = *var;               \
    *var = tmp + val;             \
    smp_mb();                     \
}

#define my_atomic_get(var) { \
    barrier();               \
    *var;                    \
}

void thread1_func() {
    my_atomic_add(b, 1);
    my_atomic_set(b, 2);
}

void thread2_func() {
    my_atomic_set(b, 3);
    my_atomic_add(b, 4);
}

void thread3_func() {
    c = my_atomic_get(b);
    c = my_atomic_set_ret(b, 10);
}

void thread4_func() {
    c = my_atomic_get(b);
    c = my_atomic_get(b);
}
```

Comment: `my_atomic_get` cannot possibly return any value.

Comment: Using GCC, the last line of a macro is a return statement.

Comment: Memory barriers **NEVER** garantee atomic modification(like increment) of variable. You need to use true atomic functions, like `atomic_add()`, for that. `And if this implementation would not work, would it work for a single writer thread with one or many reader threads?` - it depends what you mean by "work". In general, write barrier shold **prepend write operation** and read barrier should be **after read operation**.

Comment: If I prepended write operations with a write barrier wouldn't subsequent reads not see the the updated value of caused by the variable write? I guess I'm not trying to make strict atomic operations (which would require the atomic functions), I just want updated values to be seen for subsequent operations.